# Pgfplots remove darker borders on marks

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

Hi is possible remove the darker borders on marks indicated from the arrow ?

Thanks

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}        % Grafici
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma,compat=newest,%
            width=12cm,%
            height=9cm%
            }


%*********************************************************************************
% Impostazioni Pgfplots
%*********************************************************************************

\pgfplotstableread{
X Y
0.05 0.17
0.05 0.041
0.05 0.023
0.1 0.332
0.1 0.089
0.1 0.041
0.15 0.5
0.15 0.132
0.15 0.06
}\tableA

\pgfplotstablecreatecol[linear regression]
{regression}
{\tableA}

\xdef\slope{\pgfplotstableregressiona} %<-- might be handy occasionally
\xdef\intercept{\pgfplotstableregressionb}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[/pgf/number format/fixed,
legend pos=outer north east,
grid=major,
xmin=0, xmax=0.2,
ymin=0, ymax=0.6,
point meta min={0},
point meta max={0.2},
yticklabel shift=2pt,
xticklabel shift=2pt,
legend pos=north west,
legend cell align=left,
minor tick num=4,
xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex},
xtick={0,0.05,...,0.3},
minor xtick={%
0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,%
0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,%
0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,%
0.16,0.17,0.18,0.19},%
extra x ticks={0,0.05,...,0.3},
extra x tick style={
    xticklabel pos=right,
    xticklabel style={text depth=0pt}
},
extra y ticks={0,0.1,...,0.7},
extra y tick style={
    yticklabel pos=right
},
tick style={thin,black},
xlabel=\large $m$,
ylabel=\large $\Delta l$,
colorbar horizontal,
colorbar style={
    /pgf/number format/fixed,
    xticklabel shift=2pt,
    xtick={0,0.05,...,0.3},
    xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex}
},
axis line style={draw=none}, after end axis/.append code={\draw (rel axis cs:0,0) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1);},
colormap={new}{color(0cm)=(violet);color(1cm)=(blue);color(2cm)=(cyan);color(3cm)=(green);color(4cm)=(yellow);color(5cm)=(orange);color(6cm)=(red)}
]
\addplot [point meta=explicit,
    scatter,
    mark=*,
    draw=none]
    table[meta=X] {\tableA};

\addplot [mesh,point meta=x,domain=0.025:0.175,very thick,samples=10] {\slope*x+\intercept};
\addlegendentry{%
$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
\pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to remove the border from the marks completely, you can add

```
scatter/use mapped color={draw opacity=0,fill=mapped color}
```

to your `\addplot` options (`draw=none` doesn't work here).

[image]

If you want the border to be the same color as the fill, use

```
scatter/use mapped color={draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color}
```

[image]