# pgfplots mark opacity

Tags: pgfplots, transparency

I'm creating a scatter plot with pgfplots. I want circular marks with opacity=0.1. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
0 0
0.25 0.25
0.5 0.5
0.75 0.75
1 1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
        \addplot[
            only marks,
            mark size = 10,
            blue,
            opacity=0.1,
            mark=*,
        ]
        table{data.dat};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output looks okay at first glance: [image].

The problem becomes apparent however when you zoom in on one of the marks: [image]

How do I get rid of the darker ring near the outside edge? I want marks that are uniform. I have tried adding

```
scatter/use mapped color={draw opacity=0,fill=mapped color},
```

and

```
scatter/use mapped color={draw=mapped color,fill=mapped color},
```

to my `\addplot` options as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59070/pgfplots-remove-darker-borders-on-marks) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154018/pgfplots-filled-markers-without-border) but with no success.

Comment: hwy not simply add `draw opacity=0` to the normal `\addplot` options? This seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @StefanPinnow that does not change anything for me.

Comment: For me this works for your MWE as well as for a "real" scatter plot ... I'll provide it shortly as an answer so you can test yourself, because I have to leave in a few minutes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using simply `draw opacity=0` works perfectly fine for me.

```
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
0 0
0.25 0.25
0.5 0.5
0.75 0.75
1 1
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}

            \addplot [
                only marks,
                mark size=10,
                blue,
                draw=red,
                % this would also work, if you just comment `fill opacity'
%                opacity=0.1,
                fill opacity=0.1,
                draw opacity=0,
                mark=*,
            ] table {data.dat};

%            % this also works for a "real" scatter plot
%            % (this example is just copied from the manual)
%            \addplot[
%                scatter,
%                only marks,
%                point meta=explicit symbolic,
%                scatter/classes={
%                    a={mark=square*,blue},
%                    b={mark=triangle*,red},
%                    c={mark=o,draw=black}%
%                },
%                fill opacity=0.1,
%                draw opacity=0,
%            ] table [meta=label] {
%                x y label
%                0.1 0.15 a
%                0.45 0.27 c
%                0.02 0.17 a
%                0.06 0.1 a
%                0.9 0.5 b
%                0.5 0.3 c
%                0.85 0.52 b
%                0.12 0.05 a
%                0.73 0.45 b
%                0.53 0.25 c
%                0.76 0.5 b
%                0.55 0.32 c
%            };

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing a zoomed region of the above code]

Comment: That did it. Thanks! I needed `fill opacity=0.1` and `draw opacity=0` instead of just `opacity=0.1`.